# Interval datatype in MySql

Tags: mysql, types

Does MySql has the Interval datatype as PostgreSQL (or like TimeSpan in .net) does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, there is no time interval data type in MySQL.  There is a [feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20844) for one though, but apparently it hasn't gotten much attention.

The time type can be used for such a purpose though, as suggested by the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html)

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME
>   values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours
>   values). TIME values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. **The hours
>   part may be so large because the TIME
>   type can be used not only to represent
>   a time of day (which must be less than
>   24 hours), but also elapsed time or a
>   time interval between two events**
>   (which may be much greater than 24
>   hours, or even negative).

Comment: not disagreeing with your remarks about MySQL, just noting for posterity that ISO8601 5.3.2, regarding Time datatype (i.e. time-of-day), states that the day runs from 00:00 to 24:00, and 24:00 is a valid value to distinguish the start of the 24-hour day from the end of the 24-hour day. So, per ISO, a time of day value must less than *or equal to* 24 hours. Some databases are ISO-compliant on this point, others not.

Answer (score 1):

No. There are interval functions, but not datatypes.

If the intervals you're concerned with are less than 838 hours, you might be able to use the [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) type to get the behavior you want.

From the manual:

```
MySQL interprets TIME values as elapsed time rather than as time of day.
```