# ¿How to convert "Interval (differences between DateA and DateB) column" on PostgreSQL to a new colum on MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql

Am moving my database from **PostgreSQL** to **MySQL**.

I used this converter to speed up the process: http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php

The most tables are already imported well on MySQL, but I got an error message when it cames to the TimeSheet Table:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near to'
>
> interval,
>       time_alpha timestamp,
>       time_omega timestamp,
>       name varchar(6' at line 5

t
I have been reading a while around how to create the "interval column" with MySQL, like PostgreSQL uses it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL

Here is my original code with **PostgreSQL**:

```
 CREATE TABLE timesheet (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    auth_user_id integer NOT NULL,
    status_id integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    duration interval,
    time_alpha timestamp without time zone,
    time_omega timestamp without time zone,
    name character varying(64)
);
```

And here the code I have translated to **MySQL**, but that is giving me error message:

```
CREATE TABLE timesheet (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    auth_user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    status_id int(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    duration interval,
    time_alpha timestamp,
    time_omega timestamp,
    name varchar(64)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Any idea or workaround to this? thanks

Comment: There is no such Datatype as INTERVAL.

Read This:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037777/interval-datatype-in-mysql

Comment: Any idea of some type of workaround? Thanks

Comment: you can use timestamp rather.