# What is MYSQLI_TYPE_INTERVAL used for?

Tags: php, mysqli

PHP lists [`MYSQLI_TYPE_INTERVAL`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php) as a type of column returned by [`mysqli_result::fetch_field()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php).

To my understanding an interval is only a unit of measure that one can apply to date/time information. You can not select an interval as plain data in SQL, for example with a query like `SELECT INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Does anybody happen to know what `MYSQLI_TYPE_INTERVAL` is used for?

Comment: `INTERVAL` is a Data Type as defined in SQL-92, while it's not implemented in MySQL (aside from the keyword) perhaps its there for compatibility or future-proofing.

Comment: Is it registered but never used? https://lxr.room11.org/search?q=MYSQLI_TYPE_INTERVAL&project=php-src%40master

Comment: Sounds plausible. In that case `MYSQLI_TYPE_INTERVAL` can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MYSQLI_TYPE_INTERVAL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php) is reserved for the MySQL data type `INTERVAL` that has yet to be implemented by MySQL (see [bug 20844](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20844)). At this time of writing, [MySQL 8.0 offers no such datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Usually, an `INTERVAL` stores a period of time in multiple formats at the same time, like years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes and seconds. It enables more convenient calendar calculations. While other databases like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) provide that feature since way back, we are still waiting [quite some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037777/interval-datatype-in-mysql) for it to finally arrive with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

An interval is used to store a period of time. So you can use this to easily calculate when the next appointment should be for example:

This has not yet been implemented yet in MySQL, it is however registered.

The future implementation would (probably) look something like this for your amusement:

**SO THIS DOES NOT WORK (YET)!**

```
SELECT date_add(`last_appointment`, `interval_field_name`) AS `next_appointment`
FROM `appointments`
WHERE `id` = 1
```

Comment: I do not quite get what you are saying. A query like `SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS next_year;` works perfectly fine in MySQL. It would be interesting to know how the interval is 'stored', eg. how would a year be stored?

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, had a vacation. Let's say you have a different interval per customer. So you are a hairdresser and some customers come every 30 days and some come every 60 days. You could store the different interval per customer in the interval_field. This way you don't have to write the INTERVAL 30 DAYS part (which is different per customer), but just do DATE_ADD(`last_appointment`, `interval_field_name`). This interval is stored in (mini?) seconds probably. If there is a big difference in interval (30 minutes and 1 year) it is harder to do the INTERVAL 30 DAYS part yourself.